# Need advice on JSON filtering content

Tags: jquery, json

I am having an issue with my data (in JSON format). I was able to loop through my database results and display all items on the page correctly. Inside the loop, I bind a click handler to elements with a class name *showProduct*, which executes a click function callback depending on which item is clicked.

By default, the loop shows ALL items on the page. Using that class above (i.e. *showProduct*), I want the function to hide the current element (i.e. a DIV) displaying everything and filter only the content that pertains to the correct item. In other words, I just want to show whatever item is clicked from ALL items on the page and only show that one. But it needs to show the correct output (JSON) for that item.

Can anyone please help me or guide me with what I should try next?

Thanks!

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("productsSideBar").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("productsSideBar").style.width = "0";
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 
   'use strict';
  
   $.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: '',
    success: function(json){
    
    //check for window hash and display appropriate product category 
    var currentHash = window.location.hash;
    switch(currentHash) 
    {
     case '#tomatoes':
       displayTomatoes(); 
       break;
     case '#oliveoil':
       displayOliveOil();
       break;
     default:
          displayAll();
       break;
    }
    
    //display product category based on click
    $("#tomatoes").click(function(event){
      displayTomatoes();
    });
    $("#oliveoil").click(function(event){
    displayOliveOil();
    });
    $("#displayall").click(function(event){
    displayAll();
    });
     
    //display tomatoes function 
    function displayTomatoes() {
     var categoryImage = '';
    
     $.each(json, function (i, item) {
      if (item.itemCommodity == "1120" && item.itemBrandLetter == "C") {
        categoryImage += '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">'  + '<a href="#"' + 'class="showProduct" data-itemname="'+ item.itemName +'">' +
        '<img class="img-responsive img-hover productImagesCategory" src="' + item.imageURL + '">' + '<h3>' + item.itemName + '</h3>' + '</a>' + '</div>';
      }
     });
     $('#imagesCategoryProducts').hide().html(categoryImage).fadeIn('slow');
     
     $(".showProduct").click(function(event){
      
     $('#productCategories').hide();
  
     var productTitle; 
     
       $.each(json, function (i, item) {
       if ($(this).data('itemname')) {
       productTitle += '<h1>' + item.itemName + '</h1>';
       }
       });
     
     $('#productSocialShare').show();
     $('#individualProduct').show();
        $('#relatedProducts').show();  
     $('#productTitle').html(productTitle);
 
     });
     closeNav();
    }
    
    //display oliveoil function
    function displayOliveOil() { 
     var categoryImage = '';
     var location;
    
     $.each(json, function (i, item) {
      switch(item._id) 
      {
       case '':
        location = '';
        break;
       default:
        location = '';
        break;
      }
    
      if (item.itemCommodity == "2120" && item.itemBrandLetter == "C") {
        categoryImage += '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">' + '<a href="' + location + '">' + 
        '<img class="img-responsive img-hover productImagesCategory" src="' + item.imageURL + '">' + '<h3>' + item.itemName + '</h3>' + '</a>' + '</div>';
      }
     });
     $('#imagesCategoryProducts').hide().html(categoryImage).fadeIn('slow'); 
     closeNav();
    }
    
    //display all products function
    function displayAll() {
     var categoryImage = '';
     var location;
    
     $.each(json, function (i, item) {
      categoryImage += '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">' + '<a href="' + location + '">' + 
      '<img class="img-responsive img-hover productImagesCategory" src="' + item.imageURL + '">' + '<h3>' + item.itemName + '</h3>' + '</a>' + '</div>';
      
     });
     $('#imagesCategoryProducts').hide().html(categoryImage).fadeIn('slow'); 
     closeNav();
    }  
    
   
    }
   });
});
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="productsSideBar" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="#" id="displayall"><h3>View All</h3></a>
    <a href="#" id="tomatoes">Tomatoes</a>
    <a href="#" id="sauce">Sauce</a>
    <a href="#" id="oliveoil">Olive Oil</a>
    <a href="#" id="redwinevinegar">Red Wine Vinegar</a>
    <a href="#" id="balsamicvinegar">Balsamic Vinegar</a>
    <a href="#" id="peppers">Peppers</a>
    <a href="#" id="artichokes">Artichokes</a>
    <a href="#" id="olives">Olives</a>
    <a href="#" id="beans">Beans</a>
    <a href="#" id="caperspignolinuts">Capers & Pignoli Nuts</a>
    <a href="#" id="specialties">Specialties</a>
    <a href="#" id="spices">Spices</a>
    <a href="#" id="fish">Fish</a>
    <a href="#" id="brothstockssoups">Broth, Stocks & Soups</a>
    <a href="#" id="breadcrumbs">Breadcrumbs</a>
    <a href="#" id="gratedcheese">Grated Cheese</a>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="productCategories"> 
 <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-12">
              <br>
                <span class="expandSidebar" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Categories</span> 
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-12"> 
              <div id="imagesCategoryProducts"></div> 
             </div>
        </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @Taplar  added my code above. I did not include the JSON for security reasons but you get the idea. Notice under the "display tomatoes" function i have a click function called .showProduct. Thats where I am trying to narrow the items down to a specific item depending what is clicked but i dont know what to do

Comment: that is where im not sure what to do. i wasnt sure if i needed to do an if statement to match the json item to its id on click

Comment: thats the part im trying to figure out. each item in the JSON file has its own id. im trying to find a way for once I click an item it shows only that items contents. do you recommend a way i can link the JSON id to the on click event? or is there a better way? i really appreciate your help btw. im still learning

Comment: let me try that thank you!!

Comment: can you give me an example of how id format this?

Comment: ill show you what i currently have in the above code. changing it now

Comment: i just updated it ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments here is what I suggest you try.  When you are creating your elements I would suggest making a small addition.

```
categoryImage +=
    '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">'+
        '<a href="#"' + 'class="showProduct" data-itemname="'+ item.itemName +'">'+
            '<img class="img-responsive img-hover productImagesCategory" src="' + item.imageURL + '">'+
                '<h3>' + item.itemName + '</h3>'+
        '</a>' +
    '</div>';
```

If you look at the link, there is a new data element added to it of `data-itemname`.

Now you can change your click handler to use this guy.

```
          $(".showProduct").click(function(event){

             $('#productCategories').hide();

             var productTitle;
             var clickedItemName = $(this).data('itemname');


             $.each(json, function (i, item) {
               if ( item.itemName === clickedItemName ) {
                  productTitle += '<h2>' + item.itemName + '</h2>';
               }
             });
```

Possibly something like that.

Comment: that is working!!! any idea why it is duplicating though. like the item name shows twice

Comment: You may have an issue with double+ binding.  You are calling displayTomatoes when you click some #tomatoes element.  And inside that click handler you are binding to the '.showProduct' elements for a new click handler.  As such if you click #tomatoes multiple times this can result in multiple bindings on the showProduct elements which would duplicate the results.

Comment: thank you, you have been soo helpful. finally able to continue on with this project! thanks soo much!

Comment: one last thing. if i want to add to this and include data for UPC etc, do i just add it to the end of data-itemname?

Comment: The concept with data-* elements is they are a way to add custom attributes to elements.  As such if you need to associate data with the link that doesn't really fit with other tags, and you want easy access to them, then you can put them on the element with data-* elements that reflect what they are.  data-itemname, data-upc, etc.  And since these are put on the element they by nature provide you with scope, :).

Comment: One thing I will warn you about, since you have said UPC.  (I'm also in the retail realm).  You should be aware that if you have a data-* element that appears to be a number, such as a UPC, `data()` will turn these into numbers, not leave them as strings.  As such if you have leading zeros they will be removed.  If you want to bypass this one annoyance with data() then you can use attr('data-upc') to get the value and it will remain a string.

Comment: thats very helpful thank you so much. im thankful for people like you who actually take the time to help someone. have a great day!